# Associative Array Key Casting Float String

Tags: php, casting, associative-array

In my code, I have generated an associative array with keys as floats, however the PHP documentation states that when they become key's in the array they are SUPPOSED to be cast to integers. Instead, they are being cast to strings (which is actually better for me so I'm not complaining).

The problem is that when I try to access these keys using a float as the key value, it casts only the floats with .5 to integers and creates a new entry in the array. Seems like peculiar behavior.

Example:

```
var_dump( $array );
```

Output:

```
array(9) {
[0] =>
int(0)
[1.25] =>
int(0)
[2.5] =>
int(0)
....}
```

When I try to access the value 2.5 like so,

```
array[2.5]++;
```

a new entry in the array is made at `array[2]`
However if I try to access the array at `array[1.25]++;`
I successfully add 1 to the value at key: 1.25

Any ideas?

Comment: From the documentation: `Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.`

Comment: `array[1.25]++` would not work, just like `array[2.5]++`. `array["1.25"]++` would. Are you sure you tried the code as given?

Comment: yup, strings worked thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just stick with strings all the time:

```
$a = array(
    '0' => 0,
    '1.25' => 0,
    '2.5' => 0
);

$a['2.5']++;
echo $a['2.5'] . "\n";
var_dump($a);
```

Output is:

```
1
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  ["1.25"]=>
  int(0)
  ["2.5"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: yea this works thanks! I would give you +1 but unfortunately I'm too new